# Using abstract/super class for class's internal workings. Good practice wrt Access Modifiers

Tags: java, inheritance

How do I change my mistakenly c#-ish design to work with sensible access protection in java?

Here is my super class

```
abstract class Parent {
    protected parentVariable;

    protected parentMethod() {
          //These methods and variables contain internal workings of my sub-classes
          //to avoid repetition
          // I don't want classes elsewhere in the package (that don't inherit from class) to see these.
    }
}
```

I have sub classes that have shared internal working, which I've stuck it in the super class. It's still hidden to the other classes and usable by sub classes. Wait, no: this isn't c#, this is java.

```
 Protected(c#) != Protected(java) ≈≈ Internal(C#).
 c# protected = Access is limited to the containing class or types derived from the containing class.
 java protected = Access is limited to the current package
 Everything in the package can see access these. That's far too permissive for these internal workings.
```

How do I solve this? Do I have to bring the shared code down to the sub-classes and use "private" at the cost of code repetition? Was my use of parent classes bad design in the first place? Do I have to squirrel these inheritance trees away in new packages?

Comment: You can make them package-private by not specifying any access modifier for them (this is default access). Protected stuffs are visible to subclasses no matter whether the are in the same package or different package than the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no access modifier that allows visibility to subclasses but not to classes of the same package.

But that's not such a big problem because classes in a given package are supposed to be "friend", cooperate, and be released all at the same time.

Even if they see some fields and methods that they shouldn't use, the other classes of the package are not part of any external API that you have no control on, and the protected methods are not accessible to the external code.

So, just document that these methods and fields shouldn't be used so that you or your coworkers don't mistakenly use them. Or put this class in its own package if you're really concerned about same-package visibility.

Comment: Thanks. Thought so. I'll either not bother with accessor methods or use getters just to remind myself about the ones that shouldn't be externally changed. Or yes, if i really care use  another package.